# How to change file type on renaming?

Tags: file-management

I have Android 4.0 for Galaxy Note 10.1.

How  do you rename files to change the file extension?
For example, if you have a text file extension `.xml` how do you rename to `.txt`

Comment: Use one of the many file managers availabe in the [Play store](https://play.google.com/store/search?q=file+manager&c=apps)?

Comment: question or answer?

Comment: :-) Meant more linke a hint

Answer (score 2):

Almost all File Manager apps support renaming extensions. Install one from Play Store. Some best ones are: [Solid Explorer](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=pl.solidexplorer), [ES File Explorer](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.estrongs.android.pop), [Astro File Manager](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.metago.astro), [Root Explorer](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.speedsoftware.rootexplorer).

Comment: The "Android File Manager" I have doesn't seem too, thanks for the answer...